# adding watts to a circuit

Tags: electrical

I have two 500 watt base board heaters on a circuit that is controlled by two 30 amp circuit breakers "tied together". What would be your suggested max. wattage that I could add in the form of another base board heater?

Comment: If you have to ask, you should hire an electrician.

Comment: Is this a 240 volt circuit, or a 120/240 volt circuit? What do you plan to add, more heaters?

Comment: Really folks. The asker is unfamiliar with, but accurately describing a 30A 240V breaker (which can be a single double-width breaker, or can literally be two 30A single-width breakers with the handles tied together - not commonly done now, but quite commonly seen "in the field."

Comment: yep the last responder is correct. two 30's with handles tied together. I appreciate your help. Sorry it was not explained well. But still the question - what would be the largest heater I could add to this circuit

Answer (score 3):

You have a 30A 240V breaker (pair tied together) so this is a 240V circuit. You have 2X 500W on it now, or a load of 4.2 amps. You can add 9 more 500w heaters without violating the derated (80% capacity) load for heating circuits (which are considered as continuous use, i.e. more than 3 hours likely)

You can run a maximum of 5760 watts on this circuit (as derated properly.) In 500 Watt chunks that only gets you 11 - if you have some other combination that adds up to 5760 or less, you can run that combination.

This does assume that the wire is correctly sized for the breaker - such as 10 AWG copper or larger (size, smaller gauge number.)

Comment: thanks for the response - the circuit however is 120V. How does that change your answer? would it be a max. 2880 on the circuit leaving room for an additional 1880?

Comment: @MMullaney if this is in North America, and you've got a duplex breaker with the handles tied together, that's a 240v circuit.

Comment: Yes, 2880 on 120V - but it makes no sense for it to be a 120V circuit with the breaker combination you describe - It could be a MWBC (two hots and a neutral) but it's very odd to see a 30Amp MWBC...OTOH, it's very common to see 240V (only) circuits running with hot (L1) on black and hot (L2) on white.

Comment: Could be a MWBC used to supply two 120 volt heating circuits. @MMullaney  How many wires are in the cable leaving the panel? What color are the wires that are attached to the double pole breaker?

Answer (score 1):

1000 watts at 120v is 8.33 amps. You could double that and still be within the NEC's 80% load recommendation (24 amps).

http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/electric/watt-volt-amp-calculator.htm